# Best multi-port modem to use with a Hylafax server?

Tags: modem, fax

I need to figure out what modem to use with 6 external lines or more for a fax2email gateway server using hylafax.  I could go with something internal or external on a PC, but I need to be able to handle multiple incoming fax lines.  I have a working 1 line model using a parallel cabled modem. What modem would you recommend?

Comment: Will this be 6 RJ-11 jacks or delivered via T1?

Answer (score 2):

Although the project never got past the planning stages, we spent a lot of time looking at something similar about 5 years ago, and decided that [DialLogic](http://www.dialogic.com/products/) was the brand we were going to go for. We needed 12 RJ11 interfaces.

They're very expensive brand new, but occasionally you can find second hand ones floating around for a fraction of their retail price, although you can still expect to fork out several hundred dollars for a second hand one.

Comment: Keep in mind that the support they provide is non-existent, to the point that they won't provide drivers directly.  Having said that, I have used Dialogic's Brooktrout board with GFI Faxmaker, and it works very well, handling heavy fax traffic for a large law firm.